# How can I use a url to search for text in a different html page without leaving the page with the url?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url

I want to use JavaScript/Node.js to find a specific word/value after the word 'status: ' that exists in a html page. I want to do this so that I can display this word/value on the SAME html page that contains the url that forwards the user to the html page in which 'status: ' exists. How can I do this?

I have tried to look up ways to do this but having a hard time. Would it combine some sort of a curl request and regex?

The way this should work is I, the user,should be able to go to a page where I can see 'passed' (or some other value) because this page contains a url that forwards the user to a separate html page that says 'status: passed', for example .

Comment: You could try using an iframe to load the other page, perform some javascript in it to search, then display whatever you need to (and close the iframe).

Answer (score -1):

Solution: The link will be open when the mouse moves over the text. It returns a newly-created window, or NULL if the call gets failed.

Syntax:

```
window.open(URL, name, Specs)
```

Parameters: This function accepts three parameters as mentioned above and described below:

- **URL**: It is an optional parameter. It is used to specify the URL of the web page which needs to open. If the URL is not specified then a new window is open.
- **Name**: It is an optional parameter which is used to specify the target attribute.

  - **_blank**: The URL is loaded into the new window. It is optional.
  - **_top**: The URL replaces the current page.
- **Specs**: It is an optional parameter. It is a comma-separated list of items, no whitespace.

  - **Height**: It represents the height of the window in the pixel.
  - **Width**: It represents the width of the window in the pixel.

Note: Allow Pop-up of Web Browser.

Comment: This really does not provide a solution to the problem, it only suggests a function for the original poster to look at. This should probably be a comment, not an answer.